# How to get only the version of mcrypt in PHP?

Tags: php, mcrypt

`phpinfo()` shows:

```
several info...
mcrypt support  enabled
mcrypt_filter support   enabled
Version     2.5.8
several info...
```

But how can I get ONLY the version of MCRYPT?

For example:

```
echo phpversion('intl');
```

or:

```
gd_info()['GD Version'];
```

I searched Google but could not find an answer, and `phpinfo()` is a lot of info.

Answer (score 2):

PHP has a built-in function called `phpversion`. [ [DOCUMENTATION](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php) ]

This function allows you to retrieve the version of an installed extension.
You'd use it like so:

```
<?php
// prints e.g. 'Current PHP version: 4.1.1'
echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion();

// prints e.g. '2.5.8' or nothing if the extension isn't enabled
echo phpversion('mcrypt');
?>
```